# Проблемы с фоном CSS, HTML, Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Здраствуйте, столкнулся с проблемой, на первой странице все окей, а на второй появились полоски
Вот код:

```
<?php
    require("Labs/Web/config.php");
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row mt-5 text-center">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h2 style="color:#f0c38e">Виберіть лабараторну<h2>
                <a href="Labs/Lab1/hrybanov_example1.1.php" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg">Перша лабораторна</a>
                <a href="Labs/Lab2/hrybanov_example2.php" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg">Друга лабораторна</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
<?php?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../style.css">

</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row mt-5 text center" >
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <form action="hrybanov_example1.2.php" method="get">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <h2 style="color:#f0c38e">Введіть число яке буде помножене на 2<h2>
                        <input type="number" name="get_number" class="form-control" placeholder="Число">
                        <input type="hidden" name="from" value="hrybanov_example1.2.php">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Підтвердити</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ты показал только index.html, а где код второй страницы?

Comment: Извините, добавил второй код

Comment: @Artemij вы знаете, за что отвечает html, который вы скинули?

Comment: @Artemij а теперь скинь еще css, потому что в html я не вижу стиля отвечающего за цвет фона. И желательно сделать это при помощи Codepen.

Comment: https://codepen.io/theshaper-i/pen/XWNVXZq 
Держите, и спасибо за Codepen)

Answer (score 0):

Эти "полоски" - это где начинается и заканчивается градиент

```
background-repeat:no-repeat;
height:1000px;
```